# Node.js + Lambda + request Module causing RangeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, request

I have a problem and I can't find the solution to get my code run again.

I'm writing a skill for the Amazon Echo using Node.js and Lambda.

At first the necessary code:

```
var handlers = {

    "getLast": function () {

       var speechOutput = "";
       var time = "";
       var message = "";
       var tower = "";

       var request = require('request');

       var url = "mylink";

       request({
           url: url,
           json: true
       }, function (error, response, body) {

          if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
             var obj = JSON.parse(body); // Print the json response
             tower = obj.tower;
             message = obj.message;
             time = obj.time;
          }
        })

        var date_split = time.split(" ");
        var time_split = date_split[1].split(":");

        var message_split = message.split(":");

        if(message_split[1] == "-" || message_split[1] == " -"){
           speechOutput = "text";   
        }else{
           speechOutput = "text";
        }

        this.emit(':tellWithCard', speechOutput, skillName, speechOutput);
     }

other stuff
```

The test in Lambda is causing the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Maximum call stack size exceeded",
  "errorType": "RangeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "initParams (/var/task/node_modules/request/index.js:36:5)",
    "new request (/var/task/node_modules/request/index.js:48:16)",
    "new request (/var/task/node_modules/request/index.js:54:10)",
    "new request (/var/task/node_modules/request/index.js:54:10)",
    "new request (/var/task/node_modules/request/index.js:54:10)",
    "new request (/var/task/node_modules/request/index.js:54:10)",
    "new request (/var/task/node_modules/request/index.js:54:10)",
    "new request (/var/task/node_modules/request/index.js:54:10)",
    "new request (/var/task/node_modules/request/index.js:54:10)",
    "new request (/var/task/node_modules/request/index.js:54:10)"
  ]
}
```

The error is happening in the index.js of the request module:

```
'use strict'

var extend                = require('extend')
  , cookies               = require('./lib/cookies')
  , helpers               = require('./lib/helpers')

var paramsHaveRequestBody = helpers.paramsHaveRequestBody


// organize params for patch, post, put, head, del
function initParams(uri, options, callback) {
  if (typeof options === 'function') {
    callback = options
  }

  var params = {}
  if (typeof options === 'object') {
    extend(params, options, {uri: uri})
  } else if (typeof uri === 'string') {
    extend(params, {uri: uri})
  } else {
    extend(params, uri)
  }

  params.callback = callback || params.callback
  return params
}

function request (uri, options, callback) {
   if (typeof uri === 'undefined') {
     throw new Error('undefined is not a valid uri or options object.')
   }

   var params = initParams(uri, options, callback)

   if (params.method === 'HEAD' && paramsHaveRequestBody(params)) {
     throw new Error('HTTP HEAD requests MUST NOT include a request body.')
   }

   return new request.Request(params)
}
```

Has anybody an idea what is happening here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you post the whole Lambda code here? This would help understanding what happens at line 54

Comment: Hey, I've updated my question and added some code. The error is happening in the index.js of the request module. So in my opinion it has nothing to do with my code. But I don't understand what I can do. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Hey @mark96 , it's common to have a bug in your code that causes an exception to be thrown in a module you're using. It doesn't necessarily mean the module has a problem. If the module has a default stack size, which your script exceeds, I'd expect to see something like this. Is there more code to your Lambda. I feel like there is more code than what we're looking at.